# How to search duplicate records and order by columns from MSSQL Table without primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I getting top 20 record from SQL Table 
 
There is a column State in My MS SQL Table there are some numeric data,

In my case I skipped numeric records from C# function after I am getting duplicate results of City and Country, 
for example 'Los Angeles','Venezuela' coming duplicates if I skipped state numeric data 
**How to remove/delete duplicate entries if the 'state' field contains numeric** using SQL scripts

also I want to get top records from the Country 'United states' in Descending order

I wrote query as below:-

```
  Declare @sCity varchar(100),
    SELECT     Top 20  City,State,Country   
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Locations]  
    WHERE   
        City like  @sCity+'%'   
    ORDER BY    
            [dbo].[AllWorldLocations].Country DESC,         
            [dbo].[AllWorldLocations].STATE ASC, 
            [dbo].[AllWorldLocations].City ASC
```

my table is like that
[image]

I want to get records  descending order by country

```
Los Angeles             California   United States
Los Angeles             Texas        United States
Los Angeles Subdivision    Texas        United States
```

Comment: First hit on google
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/169.cfm

Comment: Thanks @Magnus Do you know is it any way to search distinct record if state contains numeric character in SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find duplicates:
http://petefreitag.com/item/169.cfm

Filter numeric characters:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx